# task taking longer then weekly working days

Tags: project-management, ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

I have a suppliers that work only Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday. 
I configured the ms project calender to be Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday . 
Now when I make a short tasks it splits the task between weeks .
But if I make a 5 days task that start on Monday its not make part of the task on mon-web (3 days) and next week mon-tue ( another 2 days ) but make the task Mon-fri 
How can I fix it ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

[Changing the project calendar](http://mscommunity.net/blogs/lugospod/archive/2007/11/23/changing-the-project-calendar-custom-working-times.aspx)

Comment: As I said , I changed the ms calendar

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you change the calendar that you go back and use the calendar in your project.

From the  link in the first answer:

> But be aware that when you change the projects default calendar, you
>   will not change the calendar for existing tasks and resources, so you
>   will have to do that by hand.

If the task already existed it might be using the wrong calendar.